# Where are there working exdamples for QSV enabled ffmpeg filters?

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, intel

I'm re-posting this question in a modified form because I'm told that stack overflow doesn't allow anyone to ask for the location of documentation.  So now I'm not asking for documentation, I just want working examples of how the QSV enabled filters are used, with a specific question on why async doesn't work with vpp_qsv .

I have a PC running Windows which is QSV capable. I've found the codec and at least one QSV filter which really speed up decoding and encoding AVC (x264) videos.

But the experience is extremely aggravating, as I cannot find a list anywhere that I can find on what the filters and arguments actually are.

The closest I've come for vpp_qsv is this:

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_vpp_qsv.c

It's a good start, but it has no examples of what the arguments actually are.
Source code doesn't explain how the filters actually work.  However, this source code does say that async_depth is a valid qualifier.

The few examples I've been able to find in various places (including stackoverflow) do not work.

By experimentation, I've found that this works:

ffmpeg -hide_banner -init_hw_device qsv=qsv -hwaccel qsv -i "input.mts" -c:a aac -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryslow -vf "vpp_qsv=cw=628:cx=0:w=640:h=480" -q:v 30 "output.mp4"

I can add other things to the filter. For example:

"vpp_qsv=deinterlace=2:cw=628:cx=0:w=640:h=480"

will work. However, this will NOT work:

"vpp_qsv=cw=628:cx=0:w=640:h=480:async_depth=4"

even though there are examples posted that say it will.

[Parsed_vpp_qsv_0 @ 0000000005bff8c0] Option 'async_depth' not found [AVFilterGraph @ 0000000007327dc0] Error initializing filter 'vpp_qsv' with args 'cw=628:cx=0:w=640:h=480:async_depth=4' Error reinitializing filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

I also have been unable to find good examples of using more than one QSV enabled filter at the same time.

I'm using the newest version of ffmpeg I can find:

I:\ffmpeg -version ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml 2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enab le-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --ena ble-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-lib zimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang - -enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine - -enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libv orbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100 libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100 libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100 libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100 libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100 libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100 libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100 libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100

and the output of "ffmpeg -filters" says I have the various QSV enabled filters on my system.

I have searched dozens and dozens of sites including Intel and ffmpeg.org and I cannot find a clear explanation of how the various QSV enabled filters work, with examples that will actually execute on my system. Could someone please point me to where this filter is explained?  (This is NOT, I repeat, NOT a banned request for documentation.  I'm asking how to use a specific qualifier in a specific filter.)

Comment: You're still asking for links to off-site examples.  Instead, just ask for an example.  You don't care whether someone finds it convenient to copy/paste and link to an existing one they know of, or write a new example, since a valid SO answer to the question you should be asking will *contain* an example.  The point of the rule is to make SO Q&As self-contained, with links only for extra info so the answer is still useful after link rot.

Comment: async_depth is only available in the git builds. 4.5 is the first release it will be in.